# What does where clause mean in trait definition?

Tags: rust

I recently encountered a code snippet that basically has following structure:

```rust
trait ToSomething { type TargetThing; }
trait ToString: ToSomething where Self::TargetThing: AsRef<str> {}
struct A<T: ToString> { a: T }
```

What does the second line mean? I thought that it means that everything that implements `ToString` should (1) implements `ToSomething` and (2) `Self::TargetThing: AsRef<str>`. However, the compiler claims that the second constraint may not hold:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as ToSomething>::TargetThing: AsRef<str>` is not satisfied
```

And I need to change the third line into `struct A<T: ToString> where <T as ToSomething>::TargetThing: AsRef<str> { a: T }` to get it working. Isn't this trait bound enforced by `ToString` trait? I'm confused.

Comment: The clause is *enforced* when implementing the trait but its not *implied* when using the trait. I believe this will work as you expect if [RFC 2089: Implied Bounds](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2089-implied-bounds.html) is implemented.